# How to Remove I/O lock from PDF while modifing it?

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I'm writing a python script to generate PDF using ReportLab. So whenever i made changes to my python script, i must have to close the pdf and again re-open it to see the changes. Even i can't compile python script while pdf is open. It produces the error ,

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'XYZ.pdf'
```

Is there any way to see the changes without closing the pdf ?. Any idea or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Windows, download and use SumatraPDF. It will let you view a document without locking it for writing, and it will even auto-refresh when the file changes.

Comment: Oh Great.. The exactly what i want ..SumatraPDF rocks.. Thnx alexis for suggesting it. for now i am using it but in future i will love to know how to code it manually in python..:-)

Comment: Glad that worked for you. I guess I misunderstood your situation: You are using another python program to "see the changes" in your output? Just modify the reader so that it opens the file, immediately reads the entire contents, and closes the file again. If you need to detect when to re-read the pdf, check for modification with os.stat.

Comment: Okay i will check it out.. thnx..:-)

Comment: Seems like Foxit Reader locks PDF files for writing while PDF file is open. SumatraPDF detects changes and re-load files without Python script throwing that IOError. It just works like Evince on Linux/GNOME. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Your pdf viewer application locks the file on purpose: because it is not prepared to handle live changes in the file. You could write a GUI application that integrates some pdf viewer library, and handle the opening and closing of the file in a way that does not bother the user.

Comment: Thnx for reply, but how to develop such a kind of mechanism in python any idea or suggestion :-). . ??

Comment: @MoinAhmed That's a rather broad question, but I see you found a workable solution in the other answer.